# Suggestion: Tag-Clicking Behavior Enhancement

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Similar requests have been made regarding tag-clicking, but I wanted to additionally suggest a feature similar to how [site removed] behaves.

My proposal is that when you click on a tag, a small menu would appear which offers the following choices:

- Ignore tag
- Interesting tag
- Other questions with this tag

Previous requests have mentioned things like adding a plus/minus selector, which would occupy more space on the base UI. A menu that appears dynamically would be an ideal way to direct the user to his or her intended action.

One final touch would be to allow users to configure a default action, if they don't want the intermediate menu.

**Edit:**

This has been implemented, nice work, devs!

**Edit #2:**

The site I originally linked has changed significantly since I posted this, and is no longer a good example. The implemented behavior of the menu is not as requested, exactly, but serves a useful purpose.

Comment: Does your proposal mean, that I have to click two times, when I want to see the other questions of a tag? First time I click the tag, second time I have to click the choice option "Other questions of this tag"?

Comment: Yes, with the proposal as-is. However a hover could be utilized, and you only would then need to click once after hovering the tag for a moment.

Comment: Has this been fully implemented? How do I indicate that I want to ignore a tag on the new drop-down?

Comment: @camainc There's a drop down menu now, but it's for the faq, wiki, etc. To ignore tags you need to enter them in the sidebar "Ignored Tags"

Comment: JYelton, that is a real pain...there are more tags that I want to ignore than those that I want to follow. I think adding a link to the menu to ignore that tag would make the system much more user-friendly.

Comment: @camainc I agree - it was why I originally proposed this feature. I admit that the SE crew is going a generally good job, though.

Answer (score 2):

I very rarely want to add a question to my list of interesting tags, or my list of ignored tags. I want to (almost every time I visit the site) go look at questions on a particular tag. I imagine other users behave similarly, after initially getting things set up, so I wouldn't be a fan of a change like this.

Don't make me click!

Comment: I am just suggesting that some users don't want to see questions pertaining to the tag, but rather do something with the tag itself, such as ignore or favor it. I just find that to add interesting (or ignore) tags having to go maintain a list of them seems distracting when I could have just as well dynamically added it to one of those lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this --what I presume is-- request that led to the click-star functionality that exists today. If I could make a small suggestion to improve this:

Put the current state of the toggle in the `<title>` text, like: [image]

Comment: Not sure this is what led the team, otherwise a dev would have given answer and mark it status completed. More likely they did it on their own, missing this request. So think it's better to post new feature request, personally I like your idea.